# How can i select two elements with id in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

There's anyway to merge the elements of javascript to decrease the code size?

```
<form>
   <input id="input1" type="text"/>
   <input id="input2" type="text"/>
</form>

//javascrypt
document.getElementById("input1").onkeypress = function(e) {
   var chr = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
   if ("1234567890qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPLKJHGFDSAZXCVBNM".indexOf(chr) < 0) return false;
};
document.getElementById("input2").onkeypress = function(e) {
   var chr = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
   if ("1234567890qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPLKJHGFDSAZXCVBNM".indexOf(chr) < 0) return false;
};
```

Comment: Name the function and reuse it?

Comment: You could select by "class" as opposed to "id".

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("#input1, #input2")` will give you a `NodeList` containing both of them. But note that it's a *list*, so you'd have to loop through it to assign that handler ([more here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can reduce the size by creating an event handler and use that event handler in both cases,

```
<form>
   <input id="input1" type="text"/>
   <input id="input2" type="text"/>
</form>

//javascrypt

const keyPressHandler = (e) => {
   var chr = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
   if ("1234567890qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPLKJHGFDSAZXCVBNM".indexOf(chr) < 0) return false;
};

document.getElementById("input1").onkeypress = keyPressHandler;
document.getElementById("input2").onkeypress = keyPressHandler;
```